# Sonicwall and vlans single wan IP use for public wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, sonicwall

Good evening,
I have a sonicwall nsa2400 with single wan interface assigned with single wan ip. My ISP only provides me one static IP address. X1 is connected to the main lab switch to provide network connectivity and internet access to workstations.

I would like to design a simple and secure way to provide an Route on a vlan or a seperate interface to provide public wifi connection to guests that will totally be isolated from the private network.

Answer (score 1):

The sonicwall by default create the WLAN in a separate VLAN. You need to create the rule between the LAN and WLAN on your own. So it's by default secure.

Comment: How would I pass the vlans yo the access points? Because the access points have a single network connections. But allow multiple ssids on different vlans.

Comment: @Learnt Do you use sonicpoint? If no, then you fall in your lan with a normal accesspoint